# Refer a connectionstring from web config in another config file

Tags: azure, web-config, nlog

I am using NLog to write logs to my database, 
I have created a file NLog.config which is writing logs to a text file as of now. 
To write the logs to a database, I am following this [tutorial](http://justinpdavis.blogspot.in/2010/04/logging-to-database-with-nlog.html).
However, the connectionstrings for diferrent environments can be only modified in Web.config. (I am using Azure App services). Is there any way I can refer the connection string from web.config in NLog.config.
TIA

Comment: Maybe just lookup the NLog-DataBaseTarget at runtime, and assign the connectionString directly?

Comment: Another possible way is to register your own custom NLog layout renderer, that can return the wanted connection-string-value.https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Answer (score 0):

If you not using ASP.NET Core (but "full" ASP.NET), you could use `${appsetting:name=..}`

Install [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended/) with Nuget and use `${appsetting:name=..}` in your config file.

e.g.

```xml
<target name="database" 
        type="Database"
        connectionString="${appsetting:name=myConnectionString}"   />
```

See also the [`${appsetting}` documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer)

NB: It can only read `<appSettings>` and not `<connectionStrings>`